# Failed to process File Error occured while processing Fastq file on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, bioinformatics, fastq, rna-seq, sequencing

when I tried to process Fastq file, the followed error occured. Can anyone help me solve this error?

[The error is shown in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxWBO.png)

I tried this code:./run_swift_sarscov2_docker.sh -v sarscov2_v2_masterfile.txt
I am expecting bam file to be generated.